# Can you Leap while standing on uneven ground?

Tags: movement, pathfinder-2e

[Uneven Ground](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=456) says that you need to Balance:

> Uneven ground is an area unsteady enough that you need to *Balance* (see Acrobatics) or risk falling prone and possibly injuring yourself, depending on the specifics of the uneven ground.

[Balance](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=28) seems to say that the only way to move is to roll an Acrobatics check:

> You move across a narrow surface or uneven ground, attempting an Acrobatics check against its Balance DC.
> **Success** You *move* up to your Speed, treating it as difficult terrain (every 5 feet costs 10 feet of movement).

This seems to exclude flight, or the Jump spell, which makes no sense.
But can you also jump, for example with [Blast Boots](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=1104) that don't require a running start? Can I avoid rolling for Acrobatics?

Comment: Isn't jumping a form of movement? Wouldn't it just reduce your jump distance by half?

Comment: Are you thinking about leaping to more uneven ground to avoid the Acrobatics check, or are you more thinking jumping off of the uneven ground to get to safety?

Comment: @MichaelRichardson I have no idea what you're referring to. Uneven ground is not difficult terrain, and difficult terrain does not (usually) apply to Leaping/other jumping.

Answer (score 2):

### Balance is weird.

I want to point out that to begin with. Nothing about narrow surfaces or uneven ground says you can't otherwise move, only that you *must* balance. Balance itself doesn't explain any further since its there to inform you['re GM] how to adjudicate attempts to Balance. There doesn't seem to be any reason to use it *other* than narrow surfaces and uneven ground saying you must.

### My interpretation: you can Leap if you already Balanced

For my money, and the way my group has run it the couple times it has come up, is that [Balance](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=28) is an 'Action tax' for spending at least part of your turn on precarious ground. You *must* spend at least one Action Balancing in order to remain there (similar to the rules for [flying](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=94)). Once you do so, you are then able to continue taking your turn as you otherwise would have, including performing other Move actions. While neither type of terrain specifies it, we generally count them as Difficult Terrain when performing non-Balance movement.

Answer (score 2):

## You Need to Balance

With no other rules covering what a character can do while standing on uneven ground we're left with one pretty strict requirement:

> Uneven ground is an area unsteady enough that **you need to Balance** (see Acrobatics) or risk falling prone and possibly injuring yourself, depending on the specifics of the uneven ground.

The rule doesn't mention only applying when trying to move, so technically the *only* thing a character can do on uneven ground or [narrow surfaces](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=455) is Balance. Even further, such a character *must* Balance for as long as they are in those types of [terrain](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=452).

### Should You be Able to Leap?

Balancing is likely more restrictive than it needs to be, and the Success and/or Critical Success entry should allow for other types of movement like Leaping. This would enable characters with sufficient acrobatic skill to perform acts of [trapeze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapeze) artistry, definitely something reasonable to support.

Characters with a fly speed should probably still need to Balance if they're standing on these types of terrain, but they would be able to [Arrest a Fall](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=91) if they fail.