# Can you Crawl while on uneven ground?

Tags: movement, pathfinder-2e

[I think it is sufficiently different from the previous question concerning jumping.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/207751/can-you-leap-while-standing-on-uneven-ground)

Assume you character is not trained in Acrobatics, but somehow finds itself on [Uneven Ground](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=456). You do not have viable ranged options, so you have to get to the enemy/other side of this ground.

**Is your only option to hope for a 20 on the Balance check, or can you [Crawl](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=76)?**
If you cannot crawl, what can you do?

Balance *is* quite unclear.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Yes, you can crawl

If you fail to balance, the consequence is you fall prone:

> Uneven ground is an area unsteady enough that you need to Balance (see Acrobatics) or **risk falling prone** and possibly injuring yourself, depending on the specifics of the uneven ground.

When you crawl you are already prone. You cannot risk to fall prone, if you are already prone, so uneven ground does not affect you when crawling.

> **Requirements** You are prone and your Speed is at least 10 feet.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that it depends on the characteristics of the Uneven Ground.

Yes, the rules are pretty straightforward, if you walk you have to roll for balance or you risk to fall to the ground.

But this can apply to lots of different terrain situations. For example, a lava floor where some rocks emerge cold from the burning lava. You can move with small jumps, even balancing from stone to stone on long strides, but you cannot crawl from stone to stone. This is a definition of an uneven ground where you cannot crawl and a fail in balance will result in a much more dangerous situation than just falling.

Other example could be a chasm crossed by a narrow branch or tree. You have to balance to cross through the terrain and risk to fall (to whatever could be down there), but in this situation, and depending on the nature of the "bridge" closing the gap, you'll be able to crawl.